# How can I keep a folder on a remote server in sync with a local folder in iOS accessible via Files?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, data-synchronization, ssh, file-sharing

I prefer not sideloading apps onto my devices, so solutions leveraging existing products are preferred.

I tried using Nextcloud, but I don’t know how to accomplish my goal of a synced folder with it, and it is slow.

PS: I have Blink installed.

Comment: The server, is it yours or are 3rd-party cloud services like Dropbox, or MS OneDrive acceptable?

Comment: @SteveChambers Mine.

Comment: I recommend [**Resilio Sync**](https://www.resilio.com/individuals/), which is free to sync folders for personal use, but has the option to upgrade for more features.  But for a long while, I was totally fine just using the folder sync capability, and only upgraded when there was a special offer on.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the maintainer of the snap package, and learned how to do this with Nextcloud:

> The way I've done this in the past is to move files into
>   the files directory of the user's slice of the datadir, make sure
>   permissions were the same, and then run occ files:scan --all. In the
>   snap it's the same, and the command is nextcloud.occ files:scan --all.
>   Unless you've put the data elsewhere, the data is
>   in /var/snap/nextcloud/common/nextcloud/data/.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use something like Dropbox, but if you need to sync a specific folder, you could try Resillo Sync (formerly BitTorrent Sync):

https://www.resilio.com/individuals/